# How to get the alias name from URL IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a MVC application and published to IIS. But instead of the default web site, I've created a new application under the default web site. Looks like this: http://localhost/srm this is the default landing page which is login form. http://localhost/srm/serviceentry this controller after successful login. But I want to get the whole url http://localhost/srm

Because I'm getting **404 Not found** after deploying it to IIS, but in IIS express I can call the controller.

```
var pathname = window.location.host;
var origin = window.location.origin;
var siteURL = "http://" + pathname + "/";

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: siteURL + 'serviceentry/SetNewTech',
  data: {
    Tech: value_check,
    OrderNo: so_no
  },
  success: function(response) {
    if (response != null && response.success) {
      alertify
        .success(response.responseText);

      $("#technician").val(value_check);

    } else {
      alertify
        .error(response.responseText);
    }
  },
  error: function(response) {
    alertify
      .error(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: You should be using the `UrlHelper` class to generate URLs in your views, e.g. `@Url.Action("SetNewTech")`.  Then if you need them in a javascript file, pass them as a parameter to a javascript function.

Comment: @Joe thank you, didn't know that is possible.